# Which is the cheapest way to get to Isla Juventud in Cuba?

Tags: budget, public-transport, cuba

[WikiVoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Isla_de_la_Juventud) states that you can get to Isla Juventud (Nueva Gerona) by plane or by boat:

> The boat ("Kometa" catamaran) costs 50 pesos per person (25 for
>   children of less than 12 years of age):
>
> 50 CUC for foreigners
>
> 50 CUP for locals.

I've checked with Cubana and the price to go by plane is around 40 CUC per leg. The Lonely Planet (2007) explains that there are other ships, not just the Kometa.

There is a bit weird to pay more for a 2 hours road trip plus a 3 hours ship trip than for a comfortable 30 minute flight... Is this information right? Which is the cheapest way to get to Isla de la Juventud for a non-local?

Comment: @pnuts possibly an answer in the making.

Answer (score 5):

Well, yes it sounds weird because it is weird.

The 50 CUC on "Kometa" is round trip ([see here](http://isladelajuventud.com/)) that includes a transfer from bus station to Port as far as I can tell but as mentioned on the page: "expect a lousy ride".  On the bus that is.

The flights are available too.  Served by [Cubana](http://www.cubana.cu) for $82/pp round trip.  So it's up to you what you would like to do.

Or you can take [Bellamar](http://isladelajuventud-cuba.com/shipping_lines.html) for 5 hours and 30 pesos.

Those are the only options as far as I can tell so for as far as time/price = worth I'd take a plane but it's your choice.

Comment: Bellamar ferry is no longer available. I was asking about this topic in Habana and the two options you have now are Kometa and Cubana and the prices are those you mentioned.